# Android Mobile App Push Notification

Tags: android, database, push-notification

I am attempting to make an Android app which will allow a user on a queue system to be notified if it's near his turn.

I would like to know if it's possible to make an Android App, that would upon connecting to the internet, connect to a server and then get assigned an ID, which would compare it to other IDs and check it's position on a queue. If it's"for examnple" less then 10 people in front of the user, to send a push notification, even if the app is closed, saying it's almost the users turn.

If it is possible, is there any tutorial available on the matter? I searched a while, and nothing of what i found appeared to be my solution.

Wrong choice of words perhaps.

EDIT: What i am asking for, isn't a tutorial to build the whole app itself, only a tutorial to make automatic push notifications upon connecting to the internet basically

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: There is no such in built tutorial available in market. You can develop your own system.

Comment: why client have to request server about his queue continuously? server should know users' queue status, if users' queue status is ready, server may push notification to user.

Comment: @calvinfly That would also work as well

Comment: you may develop server system your own. for push notification, it should be easily found tutorials.